# Investigating the convergence of a complex series along its boundary of convergence.

Tags: complex-analysis

I can easily see why the complex series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty nz^n$$ has a radius of convergence of $1$. My professor claims that the series diverges everywhere along the boundary, i.e., when $z$ belongs to the unit circle, but I am at a loss of how to show this.

My only thoughts were to take the modulus of the sum and to apply the triangle inequality to see that when $|z|=1$ we have $$\left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty nz^n\right|\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty n$$ which diverges, but this of course does not give me any worthwhile information.

Does anyone have a useful hint?

Comment: There is a nice proof down here.but just a caveat : the field of complex numbers is not an ordered field and we cannot say $z<b$ unless we know a priori that both $z$ and $b$ are real.

Comment: Oh, right, I forgot my absolute values. (Even then I am not sure if what I did was entirely correct.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ to converge, you require $a_n\to 0$. If $a_n=nz^n$ and $|z|=1$, do we have that $a_n\to 0$?

Comment: Oh, was it that simple? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If the term does not go to zero, you can't get convergence. Each term has absolute value $n$ which goes to infinity.